# Can't build anymore : OutOfMemoryError Java Heap Space

Tags: codenameone

I can't build any app anymore :

```
Your build size is: 23552kb
Sending build request to the server, notice that the build might take a while to complete!
Sending build to account: xxxxxx@gmail.com
C:\workspace\nutriplanning\build.xml:101: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

In pricing it said

> 50mb build jar size

Two minutes before I send an other built for iOS (bigger) and it works.

Now I can't build neither iOS or Android.

I already tried to increase memory settings on Ant with no results.

What should I do ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: This isn't a limit from the build servers it's an IDE configuration issue. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Intellij community version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a handy guide for this:

[image]

From [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-intellij-idea-ram.html).

Comment: I had two elements in "Window 2". I deleted one and it works ... don't why a second configuration appeared but nevermind. Thank you again Shai Almog !