# Codename One server refuses builds over 20 000kb

Tags: codenameone

Hi Shai (and everyone else)

I had a similar problem 6 months ago :
[Can't build anymore : OutOfMemoryError Java Heap Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206595/cant-build-anymore-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space)

It disappears ... I didn't really understand why, but whatever It works with build over 20mb.

Yesterday morning I work on my app, sending build to codename one and all works fine.

But suddenly server started to refuse my builds
[image]

It looks it happens DURING sending the build.

If I delete some files to make my build weights under 20mb the server accepts it but continue to refuse the whole package.

Please helps me ! I can't update Nutriplanning anymore :/

Answer (score 0):

This is an Ant integration in IntelliJ issue, the workaround is explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-intellij-idea-ram.html). You just need to increase the RAM IntelliJ associated with ant.